# Angular4: default redirect does not work

Tags: angular

I have a route file which looks like this.
My `app.routes.ts`

```
// my imported files
 .
 .
 .
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WebsiteComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "job", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: 'profile/:user_id', component: ProfileComponent },
      {
        path: 'profile/:user_id/downloadResume',
        component: DownloadResumeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'profile/:user_id/profileSettings',
        component: SettingsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'detect-device/:user_id',
        component: SecureDeviceDetectionComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'network',
        loadChildren: 'app/website/my-network/my-network.module#MyNetworkModule'
      },
      { path: 'inbox', loadChildren: 'app/website/inbox/inbox.module#InboxModule' },
      { path: 'groups', loadChildren: 'app/website/group/group.module#GroupModule' },
      { path: "qa", loadChildren: "app/website/qa/qa.module#QaModule" },
      {
        path: "notification",
        loadChildren: "app/website/notification/notification.module#NotificationModule"
      },
      {
        path: 'feed',
        loadChildren: 'app/website/feed/feed.module#FeedModule'
      },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'company-registration', component: CompanyRegisterComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'two-way-authentication', component: TwoWayAuthenticationComponent },
      { path: 'resendCode', component: TwoWayAuthenticationComponent },
      {
        path: ':id/password',
        component: ResetPasswordComponent
      },
      { path: 'forget-password', component: ForgetPasswordComponent },
      { path: 'job', loadChildren: 'app/website/jobs/search/job-search.module#JobSearchModule' },
      // { path: 'jobs', loadChildren: 'app/website/jobs/jobs.module#JobsModule' },
      { path: 'unsubscribe', component: UnsubscribeComponent },
      { path: 'feedback', component: FeedbackComponent },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/routes/routes.module#RoutesModule' },
  { path: 'employer', loadChildren: './employer/routes/routes.module#RoutesModule' },
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'job' },
];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

`app.module.ts`

```
  // imported files 
 .
 .
  .

// https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/issues/218
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, "./assets/i18n", ".json");
}

const url = configuration.SOCKET_URL;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UnsubscribeComponent,
    ProfileSettingComponent,
    WebsiteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    appRouting,
    UsersModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Ng2PaginationModule,
    SocketModule.forRoot(url),
    SweetAlert2Module.forRoot(),
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    GeneralUseModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
      deps: [Http],
    }),
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TagInputModule,
    NotificationModule,
    FeedbackModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: environment.production ? HashLocationStrategy : PathLocationStrategy }, 
    SubscribeService,
    ToastrService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

when the URL is `http://localhost:4200` then it should redirect to `job` route, but it does not do that.

I am wondering why it does not work. I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Did you know that **[modules import order matters](https://angular.io/guide/router#module-import-order-matters)** ?

Comment: Will, I have put `appRouting` at last still it did not work.

Comment: Do you have <router-outlet></router-outlet> in your `WebsiteComponent` ??

Comment: Yes, I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: Do you get any error? do the rest of your routes work?

Comment: No, I do not get any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I come up with the solution. I have gone through debugging routes using `Augury`, and I realized that I have two same default routes which are `/`

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjejG.png)

According to above picture, `NotificationListComponent` and `WebsiteComponent` has `/` routes. So default routes will stay at `NotificationListComponent` at first match.

I have removed `NotificationModule` and added the required component from `NotificatoinModule` to `AppModule`. Now it works perfectly.

I answered my question because it may help others :)